# How to create generic forms in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to create 3 classes to handle all my forms.

```
class FormCreate(CreateView):
    model = MyForm
    fields = ['field_1', 'Field']
    template_name = 'the_path'

class FormUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = MyForm
    fields = ['Field_1', 'Field_2']
    template_name = 'the_path'

class FormDelete(DeleteView):
    model = MyForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('foo')
```

I can't create 3 views for each different ModelForm, is repetitive, so I'd like create a custom form, based on a model, with a different template and fields:

```
url(r'admin/gender/add/$', FormCreate.as_view(model=Gender, my_fields, template_name='template_path'), name='gender_add'),

url(r'admin/user/add/$', FormCreate.as_view(model=User, my_fields, template_name='template_path'), name='user_add'),

url(r'admin/company/add/$', FormCreate.as_view(model=Company, my_fields, template_name='template_path'), name='company_add'),
```

The forms are different, as the template and the tags, is possible with a good url string handle all this? is the right behavior? For those forms that need a bit of customization, I can always subclassing CreateForm and add my custom methods.

Thanks in advance for the support!

Comment: https://github.com/urbanairship/django-subforms

Comment: to generate forms you can use built-in Django `modelform_factory` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/models/

Comment: @madzohan thanks, but it doesn't permit to pass a template_name, success_url or a model. The form should be created from the arguments passed to as_view().

Comment: actually it does - `modelform_factory(model, fields=['Field_1', 'Field_2'])` so you have provide `model`, `fields`, `template` and `success_url`  in `as_view`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate your form using something like this:

```
def get_custom_form(model, fields):

    class _CustomForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = model
            fields = fields

    return _CustomForm
```

Or using `modelform_factory(model, fields=['Field_1', 'Field_2'])` so you have provide `model`, `fields`, `template` and `success_url` in `as_view`

And on your FormCreate view override method `get_form_class`

```
class FormCreate(CreateView):
    fields = ['name', 'code']

    def get_form_class(self):
        return modelform_factory(self.model, fields=self.fields)
```

Second part, already answered by @dukebody, in your urls you can pass kwargs in `as_view`:

```
FormCreate.as_view(model=SomeModel, template_name="some.html", success_url='some_url')
```

... and they will override default ones.

Comment: I'm more interested to modelform_factory, but if you provide a partial solution there isn't only the space for suppositions but also for confusion.

ricapping:

urls.py

url(r'admin/gender/add/$', FormCreate.as_view(model=Gender, template_name='path'), name='gender_add'),

views.py

How i can solve here? with subclass of CreateView or modelform_factory()? This is my view:

class FormCreate(CreateView):
    model = none
    fields = ['name', 'code']
    template_name = 'none'

and i got this error: NameError:   name 'none' is not defined

Comment: `as_view` is a class method and those kwargs that you passed to it is init kwargs (passed to __init__ method of View class) https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L63 so you don't need to assign `model` or `template_name` or whatever if later it will be passed to `as_view`

Comment: Just remove `model = none` and `template_name = 'none'` from definition of `FormCreate` and pass this kwargs to `as_view` with non-dummy values

Comment: Thanks for the answer, instead to work in this way, i can create my forms in a separate file (forms.py - http://dpaste.com/2T94VJH ), update the URLconf in this way: http://dpaste.com/1FZB63J and then update the view: http://dpaste.com/2PS19XY but it raise the error "template_name" from base.py: TemplateResponseMixin requires either a definition of 'template_name' or an implementation of 'get_template_names()'

Comment: you said to use get_form_class(self): but this method is not called automatically when i create an instance of FormCreate.

Comment: actually it does if you inherit `CreateView`, because `CreateView` inherits `ProcessFormView` in declaration of that `form_class = self.get_form_class()` and after `form = self.get_form(form_class)`. So if you don't override `self.form_class` or `self.form` manually on your view it will yields your overrided `get_form_class` method (base one declared in `ModelFormMixin`) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview

Comment: it works, but i can't vote you up because i don't have enough score :(

Comment: simply accept answer) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0):

You can generate them. Example with add:

```
models = (Gender, User, Company)
extra_urls = (url(r'admin/' + type(model).__name__ + '/add/$',
                  FormCreate.as_view(
                      model=model,
                      my_fields,
                      template_name='template_path'),
                  name=type(model).__name__ + '_add')
              for model in models)
```

and append this to your urlconf.

Comment: I didn't understand, the question was about how to pass arguments to as_view() method and receive these arguments to create different Forms. For example, why in the view function this doesn't work: model = self.kwargs['model']

Answer (score 0):

By default, as_view() lets you override attributes set directly on the class, and only those. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#simple-usage-in-your-urlconf and https://github.com/django/django/blob/731f313d604a6cc141f36d8a1ba9a75790c70154/django/views/generic/base.py#L47

If you want to add more arguments to control what the form does, just put them in the class definition:

```
class FormCreate(CreateView):
    model = MyForm
    fields = ['field_1', 'Field']
    template_name = 'the_path'
    tags = ['tag_1', 'tag_2']
    pony = True
```

Your will be able to override them for each case using as_view().

Inside the view methods, refer to them as self.attrname, not self.kwargs['attrname'].

Comment: with model = self.model i got the error: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: You need to read self.model from inside a method in the FormCreate class. self is the convention first parameter of instance methods in Python.

Comment: Hi, yes, my problem was also that i'm new in Python. I'm just come back from the 4 chapter about classes of Learning Python by Mark Lutz. So, i should use self.data = data inside a method, but what method? if i use __init__ i can override the super class, there isn't a common pattern to do this?